# QT 5.8.0 vs2015 debug error

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2015

QT 5.8.0 vs2015 debug error

There was an error about "rc.exe"

So I solved the problem by

1. copy rc.exe, rc.dll from window kit
2. and pasted them to vc/bin

so rc.exe error does not happen but there is another error I am getting,

[image]

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you install Visual Studio Add-in (http://download.qt.io/official_releases/vsaddin/qt-vs-tools-msvc2015-2.0.0.vsix)?

Comment: @VladimirBershov There's no need to install the Visual Studio Add-in if you're using Qt Creator, which the asker is using (see the screenshot in the question.)

Comment: Thanks I solved this problem. This is about font problem. I'm in Korea and there are something error if I use Korean fonts.